# Bootstrap glyphs not showing up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get a minus glyph on my page using bootstrap 5.3.2, but it seems like it doesn't work.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="font-size:200px; color:blue; padding:20px;"></span>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think changing the question is the correct way to show this because that is what I was missing. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @isherwood stated, bootstrap-5 has no icons (except the ones it needs for stuff like accordions).

So you have some choices on how to get icons but the best option was this:

- include the bootstrap icons css in your page
- use `i` and `class="bi-dash"` to show the icon

Here's an updated sandbox: https://playcode.io/1619241

```
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <i class="bi-dash"></i>
</body>
```

If that doesn't work for you, they have many other options here: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#install